# Should functional areas be capitalized?

Tags: grammar

We are creating a pamphlet which shows Available Functions:

> Engineering
>   Manufacturing
>   Operations
>   Finance
>   Human Resources

Should they all be capitalized, and if so, should "Resources" after Human also be? They will be bulleted.

Comment: They will be bulleted

Comment: There is no rule for this. This is a style question.

Comment: Thank you for your response Roger.   I didn't see an answer in that link only because this is a bulleted list and isn't a title or in a sentence

Comment: If they're not sentences or sentence fragments, they should probably use title case.

Comment: I apologize; After reading other posts, I'm still not 100% sure which way to go.  The beginning of the bullet lists is as follows:  Available Functions:  Should functions be capitliized?  And then should I NOT capitalize engineering, manufacturing, finance, human resources in bulletts

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind assistance.  After all of your feedback, this is how I will add to the pamphlet:  Available functions: (then the following will be bullet points) Engineering  Finance   Human Resources  Information Technology  Logistics  Quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, do whatever you like, but given that these are, in effect, the titles of various functions (or departments?), then, yes, they would normally be capitalized using what's called Title Case.  Wiktionary defines [Title Case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/title_case) as *the capitalization of text in which the first letter of each major word is set in capital*.

You can read more about it in this [Grammar Monster article](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. These areas are specialised enough in your field to qualify as proper nouns: you don't mean just any human resources, you mean your human resources. By capitalising, you assign importance.

It's also a style issue, wherein you may do whatever the deuce you like.